# How to display an hexdump representation in a pyqt label?

Tags: python, pyqt, nonetype, hexdump

I am trying to display a variable with an hexdump representation in a label in pyqt. I have a variable var of type bytes.

```
print(hexdump.hexdump(var)) #the variable is printed in console with 
                             #hexdump representation                
self.label.setText(hexdump.hexdump(var)) # nothing is written in the label
```

I tried this :

```
self.label.setText(str(hexdump.hexdump(var))) # it writes "None" in the label
                                               #(same when I used repr instead of str)
```

It is to mention that when I tried some methods, I got an error saying that hexdump.hexdump(var) is NoneType.

How can I write the variable var with an hexdump representation in the label ?

Comment: What is `hexdump.hexdump`? It's not in the std library. And what exactly is `var`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I already installed hexdump and imported it, the name of the module is hexdump and the name of the function is hexdump, so  `hexdump.hexdump`  calls the function hexdump of the module hexdump if this is what you are asking. var is the result of previous operations, and  `type(var)`  returns bytes.

Comment: Please provide a link to the package you installed, and also show an example input string - otherwise, it's impossible to test your code.

Comment: I installed the package using pip (   `pip install hexdump`  ) , an example of an input (variable  `var`  )is :   b'\x08\x04\x12\x01k\x1a\x01k2\x0168\x01B\x03mm@'

Comment: Did you read the [hexdump documentation](https://pypi.org/project/hexdump/) (i.e. the Basic API section)?

Comment: yes, I understand that I can use `dump` (basic API) to have a string output. However I want to display in the label the representation obtained with `hexdump` (advanced API) and I couldn't do it because it is not of type string. So can I put that representation in a string variable ?

Comment: `help(hexdump.hexdump)`.